# How to tell what version a Snow Leopard DVD is?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, dvd

I have a Snow Leopard DVD that was copied from the original. All it says on the CD is "Snow Leopard" How can I tell what version of the DVD it is? The DVDs were only released in versions 10.6.0 and 10.6.3.

Comment: Are you asking just out of curiosity or is their a specific reason behind it?

Comment: @patrix I'm making a NetInstall image of it for a Netboot server and want to make sure I have 10.6.3 and not 10.6.0.

Comment: I have a 10.6.2 here, came together with the late 2009 iMac.

Comment: Yeah, that's an special build for your iMac. The DVDs I'm talking about are the reference releases sold by Apple in stores.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to see the OS version by going to System Preferences > Startup Disk. If it doesn't show in Startup Disk for some reason, you can run the following command in Terminal:

```
defaults read "/Volumes/Mac OS X Install DVD/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion" ProductVersion
```

If your DVD is not called "Mac OS X Install DVD" then you'll need to replace that part of the command with the actual disc name.

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why I didn't think of that.